# matlab - audioread produces verbose output and wont stop

Tags: matlab

I am using matlab and trying to plot a spectrogram from an audio file. The problem is that audioread itself gives me a huge output of numbers in the console, wont stop scrolling and will never reach the spectrogram command. The numbers look like this, and it scrolls for years.

```
   -0.0190   -0.0387
   -0.0687   -0.4357
   -0.0253   -0.1229
    0.0561    0.3603
    0.1308    0.3627
    0.1283    0.1240
    0.0004    0.0327
```

How do I switch it off?

Comment: Please post your code. Did you miss off a final semicolon?

Comment: I think you forgot to put a semi-colon at the end of your `audioread` command.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a semicolon.
Does this help?

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsgigzp-47